# Open graph meta tags added in Joomla, but Facebook still does not "fetch" my website

Tags: html, facebook, joomla, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I added the OGM tags in my Joomla website before 2 weeks, but still when I publish a link from my website in Facebook it does not "fetch" it.

[image]

```
<meta name="keywords" content="mysite,keywords" />
<meta name="og:title" content="Mysite title" />
<meta name="og:type" content="article" />
<meta name="og:site_name" content="MY SITE NAME" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your website and you're head section is empty, all meta data is actually inside body header tag.

Probably it's an issue of your template, switch to protostar default template and check if is loaded correctly in head section.